# How to get list of year in java between two value?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I try to get list of year in java. For example i want to print year from 2018 until the current year only. Anyone can help me on this ?

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail? otherwise try ```for (int y = 2018; y <= 2020; y++) System.out.println(y);```

Comment: What have you tried and what problems are you facing?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take some time to read [How to ask good questions?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also please try to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your own attempt and show it to us.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can do the following :

```
List<Integer> years = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int endYear = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
for(int year = 2018;year <= endYear; year++){
    System.out.println(year);// if you just want to print the years.
    years.add(year);// if you want to store the years in an array list.
}
```

Here, `Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR)` can be used to get the current year. As you already know the starting year(for eg 2018), we can use this to create a loop for obtaining the required result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LocalDate` or `LocalDateTime` (*jdk 8+*):

```
LocalDate fromDate =  LocalDate.of(2018, 3, 11);
LocalDate toDate = LocalDate.now(); // 2020-03-11
long yearsD = fromDate.until(toDate, ChronoUnit.YEARS); // 2 years

LocalDateTime fromDateTime =  LocalDateTime.of(2018, 3, 11, 5, 45, 30);
LocalDateTime toDateTime = LocalDateTime.now(); // 2020-01-11T10:00:00.0000
long yearsDT = fromDateTime.until(toDateTime, ChronoUnit.YEARS); // 2 years
```